# linux show process ram usage

Tags: linux

free shows that My centos system used 4/11 Gb RAM, but I can't pinpoint which process has used them.  I used top, however it only shows one process(mysqld) used about 1GB.  what's going on?

```
# free -g
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:            11          4          7          0          0          3
-/+ buffers/cache:          0         11
Swap:            1          0          1
```

```
sks:  91 total,   1 running,  90 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
Cpu(s):  0.0%us,  0.1%sy,  0.0%ni, 99.9%id,  0.0%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.0%si,  0.0%st
Mem:  12299928k total,  4372572k used,  7927356k free,    77392k buffers
Swap:  2097144k total,        0k used,  2097144k free,  3925252k cached
```

PID USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND
    1 root      18   0 10352  704  588 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.82 init
    2 root      RT  -5     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.01 migration/0
    3 root      34  19     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 ksoftirqd/0
    4 root      RT  -5     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.01 migration/1
    5 root      34  19     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 ksoftirqd/1
    6 root      RT  -5     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 migration/2
    7 root      34  19     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 ksoftirqd/2
    8 root      RT  -5     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 migration/3
    9 root      34  19     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 ksoftirqd/3
   10 root      10  -5     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.09 events/0
   11 root      10  -5     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.01 events/1
   12 root      10  -5     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 events/2
   13 root      10  -5     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 events/3
   14 root      10  -5     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.01 khelper
  119 root      11  -5     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 kthread
  126 root      10  -5     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 kblockd/0
  127 root      10  -5     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 kblockd/1
  128 root      10  -5     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 kblockd/2
  129 root      10  -5     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 kblockd/3
  130 root      15  -5     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 kacpid
  292 root      14  -5     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 cqueue/0
  293 root      15  -5     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 cqueue/1
  294 root      15  -5     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 cqueue/2
  295 root      15  -5     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 cqueue/3
  298 root      14  -5     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 khubd
  300 root      10  -5     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 kseriod
  390 root      15   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 khungtaskd
  393 root      17  -5     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 kswapd0
  394 root      17  -5     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 aio/0
  395 root      18  -5     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 aio/1
  396 root      18  -5     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 aio/2
  397 root      17  -5     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 aio/3
  603 root      11  -5     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 kpsmoused
  671 root      10  -5     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 mpt_poll_0
  672 root      13  -5     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 mpt/0
  673 root      13  -5     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 scsi_eh_0
  679 root      13  -5     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 ata/0
  680 root      13  -5     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 ata/1
  681 root      13  -5     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 ata/2
  682 root      13  -5     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 ata/3
  683 root      13  -5     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 ata_aux
  694 root      14  -5     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 kstriped
  715 root      15  -5     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 ksnapd
  753 root      10  -5     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:03.54 kjournald
  778 root      10  -5     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 kauditd
  811 root      19  -4 12668  836  400 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.53 udevd
 2331 root      11  -5     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 kmpathd/0
 2332 root      12  -5     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 kmpathd/1
 2334 root      13  -5     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 kmpathd/2
 2335 root      13  -5     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 kmpathd/3
 2336 root      12  -5     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 kmpath_handlerd
 2358 root      11  -5     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 kjournald
 2899 root      15   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 vmmemctl
 3028 root      15   0 17540 1292 1052 S  0.0  0.0   0:01.31 vmware-guestd
 3374 root      11  -4 28220  816  584 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.02 auditd
 3376 root       7  -8 16268  764  620 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.01 audispd
 3396 root      15   0  5912  672  544 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.06 syslogd
 3399 root      15   0  3808  428  348 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.01 klogd
 3413 root      18   0 10764  372  244 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.29 irqbalance
 3428 dbus      18   0 32712 1404  856 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 dbus-daemon

3477 haldaemo  15   0 49164 5152 2224 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.91 hald
 3478 root      15   0 21700 1056  872 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.01 hald-runner
 3485 haldaemo  19   0 12328  860  744 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 hald-addon-acpi
 3491 haldaemo  17   0 12328  852  740 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 hald-addon-keyb
 3500 root      16   0 10232  688  592 S  0.0  0.0   0:02.94 hald-addon-stor
 3519 nscd      15   0  199m 2044 1364 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.15 nscd
 3542 root      15   0 60748 1196  648 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 sshd
 3561 ntp       15   0 19832 5528 4424 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.03 ntpd
 3576 root      25   0 64168 1320 1056 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.19 mysqld_safe
 3601 root      15   0 73812 1052  492 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.01 crond
 3714 xfs       18   0 18416  744  480 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 xfs
 3799 root      18   0 17068  448  304 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 atd
 3923 root      25   0 58876  316  240 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 rhnsd
 3942 root      17   0  3796  492  420 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 mingetty
 3945 root      15   0  3796  488  420 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 mingetty
 3948 root      18   0  3796  488  416 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 mingetty
 3950 root      18   0  3796  488  416 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 mingetty
 3951 root      18   0  3796  484  416 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 mingetty
 3956 root      18   0  3796  488  416 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 mingetty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reading your `free`, there is 3GB used as disk cache.

Answer (score 3):

1. You can sort the processes by used memory by pressing <kbd>M</kbd> when in top.
2. Linux uses unused memory as a disk cache, it's normal behavior.

Answer (score 2):

[`ps`](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?ps) has options for this.

e.g. `ps -euf`

or

```
ps -e -orss=,size=,args= | sort -b -n
```

> **rss**          resident set size size
>   **size**         memory size in kilobytes

Answer (score 0):

If you want a more visual (yet command line) tool, htop would be a good idea. You can sort them by various options.

Answer (score 0):

`gnome-system-monitor` shows a visual representation of processes, % CPU, ID, and memory currently in use.